# Mod Rewrite URL Containing Encoded URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, urlencode

I have a website with a few external links. They all use target="_blank" to open in a new tab/window. I want to log clicks on these links, by using an internal link which logs the click, then redirects to the requested external url.

I use a simple (jQuery) function to rewrite the href of the links as follows:

```
    $("a[target=_blank]").each(function() {
        const href = $(this).href();
        $(this).href("out/" + encodeURIComponent(href));
    });
```

($.fn.href() is defined elsewhere).

This results in links with hrefs like:

```
https://example.com/out/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chartjs.org
```

So far so good.

Now I need my .htaccess to rewrite that to:

```
index.php?token=out&action=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chartjs.org
```

How do I achieve this?

I've tried everything I can think of, including:

```
RewriteRule ^out/(.*)$ /index.php?token=out&action=$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^out/([^/]+)$ index.php?token=out&action=$1 [L]
```

but can't get anything to work.

(I've also tried using [L,B] and [L,QSA] to no avail).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: "but can't get anything to work." - You should state exactly what happens. I expect you are seeing a server generated 404 response (despite having tested that `.htaccess`/mod_rewrite is enabled successfully).

Comment: You are 100% correct :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> https://example.com/out/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chartjs.org
> ```

A URL like this, with encoded slashes (ie. `%2F`) in the URL-path part of the URL will, by default, result in a 404 response *before* your directives in `.htaccess` are able to process the request. This is a "security" feature.

However, you can override this behaviour and permit encoded slashes. BUT, this can only be configured in the server-config, not `.htaccess`. For example:

```
# In the <VirtualHost> or main server config
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

Valid values are `NoDecode` (preferable) and `On`. (`Off` being the default.)

You can then use mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` to rewrite the request. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(out)/(.*) index.php?token=$1&action=$2 [B,L]
```

Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` directive is %-decoded, so you will need to use the `B` flag here to URL-encode the captured backreference.

Although, you could just rewrite to `index.php` (without explicitly passing the parameters) and instead parse the requested URL (ie. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) in PHP instead to extract the necessary information.

---

Alternatively, consider removing (or manually encoding) the `http(s)://` prefix prior to building your URL, to avoid `//` (or `%2F%2F`) from appearing in the resulting URL to begin with. (Double slashes in the URL-path are also problematic when it comes to mod_rewrite.) Also you would still potentially have issues with slashes that occur later in the URL (although they don't necessarily *need* to be URL-encoded). You could even base64 encode the resulting URL (using [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa) in JavaScript) and later [`base64_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) in PHP.